# why do I get an error code 88 in the function of connect? tcp in c

Tags: c, tcp

In my code, there is a problem.
I try to create a tcp socket , and the functions of my server(create , bind , listen) are totaly fine.

When it comes to my client, "create-function" is fine, but my "connect-function" is not good.

Here is my code of the client:

```
int tcp_socket = -1;
if (tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed with error: %d", errno);
    fprintf(stderr, "To create a raw socket, the process needs to be run by Admin/root user.\n\n");
    return -1;
}  
printf("sucess create tcp\n");
struct sockaddr_in Watch;
memset(&Watch, 0, sizeof(Watch));
Watch.sin_family = AF_INET;
Watch.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
//Watch.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ; 

// finishing open. now we coonect to the receiver address.

 int connectResult  = -1;
 connectResult = connect(tcp_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&Watch ,sizeof(Watch));
 if (connectResult == -1)
 { 
printf("connect() failed with error code : %d", errno); // cleanup the socket; close(tcp_socket);
 return -1;
 }
```

`your text`

I expect that the connect-function will be fine

Comment: Besides `errno`, also print the result of `strerror(errno)` which will give you a textual description of the error.

Comment: Or just use `perror()`.

Comment: The code that sets the address to connect to is commented out. Where are you connecting?

Comment: `if (tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == -1)` should be `if ((tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)`. You're setting `tcp_socket` to the result of `== -1`, not the socket.

Comment: What error are you getting after fixing that?

Comment: Why does the error message for `socket()` talk about a raw socket? You're not trying to create a raw socket.

Comment: Another compound exprrssion fail - just stop using them!